# Download an entire folder from a server

Tags: asp.net

I am creating a website (asp.net) that lets users upload some files to the server (only registered users can upload). All the files uploaded by a particular user are stored in one folder on the server. Now, the website will also have a search capability. anybody browsing the website can see what all files are uploaded by a user "x" and choose to download them. Lets say user "X" uploaded 100 files.

On the server side, i have code that will fetch all the 100 files and stream the files one by one in loop to the user. I have:
`Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + file.Name)`
that would prompt user for the location to save the file on their disk. For 100 files, user would be prompted 100 times.

I would like to prompt the user only once for save/open/close dialog, cache (or somehow get that location) the location to which the user is storing the files to save the rest of the files to that location with prompting user again and again.

Is it possible to do something like this?

Answer (score 1):

Can't you make a zip file ?

Using [DotNetZip](http://dotnetzip.codeplex.com/), for example ?

Comment: Zipping 100 files would take some time if the file size is large. Also, I might have to store on them on disk if I am not able to zip in memory.

Comment: With DotNetZip, you can zip to stream.
In my point of view, without ziping, you can't have a single file. Web broswer won't accept downloading several files "in one" (it may be a security flaw).

Answer (score 1):

There?
You can use [csharpziplib](http://www.icsharpcode.net/opensource/sharpziplib/) for zipping your files.
and then provide single link to user.

In case size or number of files taking up much time, you should think of alternatives, such as:

1. schedule download request and write a windows service for zipping.
2. Breaking your total files in couple of zip files basis the size counter.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on alternative 1: Schedule download request implement windows service? I did not understand that. Thanks

Comment: Maggie, You said "Zipping 100 files would take some time if the file size is large. Also, I might have to store on them on disk if I am not able to zip in memory." So here i want to tell you that if your user can submit download request. the request would be read by a windows service (scheduled service to ping for requests in queue) and there you would write code for packing stuff and update the queue status. I have implemented this solution for a banking solution where customer ask for their detailed trasactions in pdf/xls format.

Comment: In future answers, you can safely omit the salutation.

Answer (score 0):

Include a download of a text file with the download URLs in it, so something like [`wget`](http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/) ([Windows version](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/wget.htm)) can be used? (Or other downloader that can take a list of files to download.)